# White Space in Custom Status Bar Notification Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

My background color is not filling entire layout in Custom `Statusbar` view. Any idea why?

Here is screenshot (updated to simplify):

[image]

There is a padding of white space to the right of the blank black area.  Here is the complete layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:scrollbars="none"></LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Probably has something to do with this android:layout_marginLeft="-16dip" in ImageView.

Comment: try to set `LayoutWidth` to `fillParent` for `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the attempt ... but a simple blank Linear layout has the same effect. I will update my post to simplify the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with Google developers directly and this is how this view is intended.  Because I chose a black background it is visible.  Google suggests sticking with the default background color which in turn does not show this space.